# Scala, Slick, and Dates Before 1970

Tags: mysql, scala, date, datetime, slick

I'm trying to represent dates in my DB (MySQL) that can be anywhere from the year 1900 until today.  So obviously, timestamp-like values won't cut it since that only covers dates from 1970 until now.  So in MySQL, the datetime data type can work for this (although for some weird reason, using a datetime feels dirty to me).  However, for Typesafe's Slick library, the only date types supported are java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time and java.sql.Timestamp, all of which can't handle dates before 1970.

I'm thinking of craziness such as finding a way to cast the datetime to a string, and having Slick pretend it's a string, and do a conversion to an appropriate type (ex. org.joda.time.LocalDate).

Has anyone encountered this problem before, and if so, how did you deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Use DATETIME instead of TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody wrote a joda mapper for Slick: https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper